# Incrementing the current time in terms of minutes

Tags: c#, datetime

I am on a simulation application and need to attach different time with each record. I am storing the date and time in  separate strings:

```
string pdate = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();  
string ptime = DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();
```

Now I am trying to add 5 minutes to the ptime variable (this I am doing in a foreach loop).

```
foreach (loaddata dl2 in lstdata)
{
  //some code
  ptime = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5); 
  //Results in ptime with date and time(I only need the time here)
}
```

**UPDATE:** I need to add 5 minutes to the previous time in each iteration

Suggestions please.

Comment: how can you increment a string?

Comment: Oops! Made the change. I am still a bit confused with the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do this way

```
ptime = DateTime.Parse(ptime, "your string format", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                .AddMinutes(5).ToShortDateString();
```

**Problem with your code**

Store DateTime in DateTime only so you can "increment" them there itself.
Converting from DateTime to string is easy and almost error free. But conversion from string to Dateime sometimes results in exception.

Best is to do it this way

```
DateTime ptime = DateTime.Now;

// After some coding

ptime = ptime.AddMinutes(5);
```

Conversion to string should be done when you know that DateTime Format is not required like showing in UI.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you storing it in Strings when you can store it in a `DateTime`? `DateTime` is made for dates to be stored, and offers many methods to deal with manipulating date.

If you really need the string, manipulate the `DateTime` and call `ToShortDateString()` afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `DateTime` object:

```
DateTime current = DateTime.Now;

foreach (loaddata dl2 in lstdata)
{

   //some code
   current = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5); 

   string pdate = current.ToShortDateString();  
   string ptime = current.ToShortTimeString();
   // do something with pdate and ptime

   //Results in ptime with date and time(I only need the time here)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't this work?

```
ptime = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5).ToShortTimeString();
```

Comment: This will result in the same time in all my records with 5 minutes plus to current time. I want 5 min increment to the previous time with each iteration.

Comment: Right. In that case you need to store a DateTime object, as Matten suggests. You can't increment time in a String representation - you need the original thing to work with.